# android-x86 using gdb | gdbserver for debugging mediaserver

Tags: gdbserver, android-x86

May I know others experience of using (gdb and gdbserver) for debugging mediaserver (Native Binary)

After reading several blogs and mannual I am in confused state.

Still I am struggling to get symbol info needed by GDB ...

Please find the console logs ...

```
rajeshkumar@tpvgtvvm1:/media/rajeshkumar/droid_2k14/ref/ws_home/dev1$ python $AUTIL/agdb.py mediaserver
found debugger: /media/rajeshkumar/droid_2k14/ref/ws_home/dev1/android-x86/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/i686-linux-android-4.7/bin/i686-linux-android-gdb
found symbol: /media/rajeshkumar/droid_2k14/ref/ws_home/dev1/android-x86/out/target/product/x86/symbols/system/bin/mediaserver
found mediaserver, pid is: 1978
attach gdbserver to 1978, listen on port 7890

rajeshkumar@tpvgtvvm1:/media/rajeshkumar/droid_2k14/ref/ws_home/dev1$ i686-linux-android-gdb -q -x ./temp_dbg/gdbclient.cmds /media/rajeshkumar/droid_2k14/ref/ws_home/dev1/android-x86/out/target/product/x86/symbols/system/bin/mediaserver
Reading symbols from /media/rajeshkumar/droid_2k14/ref/ws_home/dev1/android-x86/out/target/product/x86/symbols/system/bin/mediaserver...done.
0x400f95a6 in ?? ()
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    Thread 1978       0x400f95a6 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x400f95a6 in ?? ()
warning: (Internal error: pc 0x8 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)

warning: (Internal error: pc 0x7 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)

warning: (Internal error: pc 0x7 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)

#1  0x00000008 in ?? ()
warning: (Internal error: pc 0x7 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)

#2  0x41717bf0 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) info sharedlibrary 
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x400079a0  0x40020059  Yes         /media/rajeshkumar/droid_2k14/ref/ws_home/dev1/android-x86/out/target/product/x86/symbols/system/bin/linker
(gdb)
```

Content of "./temp_dbg/gdbclient.cmds"

```
set solib-absolute-prefix /non_exist_dir

set sysroot /media/rajeshkumar/droid_2k14/ref/ws_home/dev1/temp_dbg/symbols/system

set solib-search-path /media/rajeshkumar/droid_2k14/ref/ws_home/dev1/temp_dbg/symbols/system/lib:/media/rajeshkumar/droid_2k14/ref/ws_home/dev1/temp_dbg/symbols/system/bin

target remote 192.168.56.102:7890
```

Below are some of the possibilities I explored, But no luck ...

1, Added LOCAL_CFLAGS:= -g -O0 ( other possible values I tried -ggdb | -ggdb3 ) at Android.mk Module level file.

2, Modified the default compiler flags at global level ( build/core/combo/select.mk | build/core/combo/TARGET_linux-x86.mk) to "-g -O0", Observed build failure at components like Audioflinger, system/core/lib. I revert back to -O2.

System info ...

1, Installed the iso image on VirtualBox.

2, used lunch option "5. android_x86-eng" to build the image.

3, git branch info (x86/kitkat-x86) "Android-x86 4.4-RC2 (KitKat-x86)"

Please let me know other possibilities ...

Answer (score 0):

When you build your project can you please include APP_OPTIM:=debug flag to generate symbol information.

Your command would look like

```
../<project-folder>: ndk-build APP_OPTIM:=debug NDK_DEBUG:=true
```

Comment: Thanks G3M. changing the default gdb and gdbserver with prebuild binary provided by chromium android_tools helped me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick hack and un-block myself, I replaced prebuild gdbserver ( GNU gdbserver 6.6 ) with chromium android_tools prebuild gedserver ( GNU gdbserver (GDB) 7.6 ) downloaded from https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools

with i686-linux-android-gdb (GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6) + gdbserver ( GNU gdbserver (GDB) 7.6 ) I am able to progress 
in my debugging with muti-threaded mediaserver application.